# how can I insert html content in amp-list

Tags: json, amp-html

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  items: [
    {
       FullImage: "87acaed5c90d.jpg",
       Title: "sometext",
       description: "<p id="imagenews"><img src='something'></p>" ,
    }
  ]
}
```

how can I insert description into a div as an html? I tried

```
<div>{{description}}</div>
```

but it was treated as plain string.

Comment: Double curly braces ({{ }}) notation is for string templating by design. Nothing wrong with the result. By the way, do you use angular or so? If, so you may add it in the labels.

Comment: I want the content in the description to be shown inside my page instead of showing a dumb string!!, like if I have an image, I'd like my image to be shown not the useless <img>tag!!!

Comment: This was a while ago but you should note you need to use `amp-img` if you want to use an image on a valid amp page.

Answer (score 5):

For items containing HTML in your JSON you have to use triple curly braces.

```
{{{description}}}
```

This will let the HTML be parsed as HTML rather than a string.

Comment: but it will be text only; not executable HTML